# How can I detect implicit conversions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to search and remove implicit conversion in many stored procedures. But it does take too much time to review each and every statement in stored procedures via execution plan to find out implicit conversion.

Please advise how can I efficiently detect implicit conversion in all stored procedures available in a SQL Server database.

Comment: Try checking Plan Cache and search for Implicit Conversion like [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/08/finding-implicit-column-conversions-in-the-plan-cache.aspx). Of course it will find only ones that were executed and cached. Or execute your stored procedure, save plan cache and search for Implicit Conversion.

Comment: You don't  need to manually review every execution plan, use DMV and query it.

Comment: Another solution [Use Extended events](https://sqlserverfunctions.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/get-told-about-explicit-implicit-conversions-in-sql-2012-using-extended-events/), SP have to be executed first.

Comment: Last solution find tool that does static analysis of code (RedGate or Apex) should have something like that

Comment: Asking for tools is explicitly off topic so I have edited your question. Though it is on 4 close votes already and I wouldn't be surprised if someone gives it a fifth without reading it.

Comment: Thanks Martin for explanation. I will take care from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Querying [DMV Cache Plans](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/01/08/finding-implicit-column-conversions-in-the-plan-cache.aspx)
2. Using [Extended Events](https://sqlserverfunctions.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/get-told-about-explicit-implicit-conversions-in-sql-2012-using-extended-events/) (SQL Server 2012+)
3. Tools that do analysis of code (RedGate/ApexSql)

Comment: Thank you @lad2025, really appreciate your help. but I still searching such type of tool instead of dmv/extended events/plan cache.

Comment: In my opinion you won't find tool that do that work for you completely  automatically. If I were you I would take Extended Events, set alarms and hunt down every implicit CAST. I know that it will take time and at first will be a lot to do. Just think about Dynamic-SQL, how without execute query that tool will know about casting problem?

Comment: great explanation. Thank So much.